# Удобочитаемый вывод RSS

Tags: xml, golang, rss

Сделал получение rss с нвостных сайтов и вывод их в консоль пока что.

Все никак не получается победить вывод. Упорно выводится все одной сплошной портянкой. Только на lenta.ru rss разделяется если добавить в него `\n`(правда при добавлении данных в html шаблон переносы снова теряются, но это уж другая тема) в остальных rss одна портянка.

Подскажите плз, как сделать вывод нормальным и понятным человеку и приятным глазу?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type General struct {
    Rss     xml.Name   `xml:"rss"`
    Channls []LevelOne `xml:"channel"`
}

type LevelOne struct {
    Channel xml.Name     `xml:"channel"`
    Itms    []ItemStruct `xml:"item"`
}

type ItemStruct struct {
    It          xml.Name `xml:"item"`
    Description string   `xml:"description"`
    //нужное поле достаточно раскомментировать, чтобы оно попало в вывод
    /* Guid        string   `xml:"guid"`
    Author      string   `xml:"author"`
    Title       string   `xml:"title"`*/
    //Link string `xml:"link"`
}

func main() {
    args := os.Args[1:]
    var text string
    for i := 0; i < len(args); i++ {
        resp := DoingAll(args[i])
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(resp)
        for scanner.Scan() {
//ниже добавлен \n для переносов, но он игнорируется. Не игнорируется только если получать rss от lenta.ru
            text += scanner.Text() + "\n"
        }
        var res General
        xml.Unmarshal([]byte(text), &res)
        fmt.Println(res.Channls)
    }
}

func CompositeReq(source string) *http.Request {
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, source, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return req
}

func MakeReq(req *http.Request) *http.Response {
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return resp
}

func DoingAll(arg string) io.ReadCloser {
    req := CompositeReq(arg)
    resp := MakeReq(req)
    return resp.Body
}
```

Comment: html шаблон нужно готовить правильно. каждую "тему" заверните в `<p>...</p>` или `<ul><li>....</li><li>...</li></ul>` или просто вместо '\n' используйте `<br>`. Но только это нужно делать с распаршенным текстом, а не в процессе вычитывания xml!

Comment: @KoVadim вот в том и дело, что я не понимаю пока что как мне в распаршенный текст(статьи) добавить элемент html. при выводе распаршенного текста он выводится как один элемент слайса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поправляем структуры

```
type ItemStruct struct {
    It          xml.Name `xml:"item"`
    Description string   `xml:"description"`
    Guid        string   `xml:"guid"`
    Author      string   `xml:"author"`
    Title       string   `xml:"title"`
    Link string `xml:"link"`
}
```

просто раскомментировал

```
type General struct {
    Rss     xml.Name   `xml:"rss"`
    Channls LevelOne `xml:"channel"`
}
```

там нет массива.

Теперь можно исправить чтение

```
for scanner.Scan() {
    text += scanner.Text()
}
```

теперь можно вывести заголовки

```
xml.Unmarshal([]byte(text), &res)
for _, item := range res.Channls.Itms {
  fmt.Println(item.Title)
}
```

ок, выведем прям для html

```
xml.Unmarshal([]byte(text), &res)
for _, item := range res.Channls.Itms {
  fmt.Printf("<h1> %s </h1>\n", item.Title)
  fmt.Printf("<p> %s </p>\n", item.Description)
}
```

конечно, там нужно добавить head и body, но даже сейчас уже норм. Но если это чуточку больше, чем для домашнего использования, можно использовать шаблонизаторы, например, встроенный https://metanit.com/go/web/2.1.php